# Solving Equations with units is not working

Tags: equation-solving, units

I have the code

```
    Clear[distance, time, Vavg]; 
Solve[Quantity[Vavg, "Meters"/"Seconds"] == 
  Quantity[distance, "Meters"]/Quantity[time, "Seconds"], distance]
```

The Answer is

```
{{distance -> time Vavg}}
```

I wonder why doesnt it shows the units in meters ...
Please help

Comment: Also tried Solve[Quantity[Vavg, "Meters"/"Seconds"] == 
  Quantity[distance, "Meters"]/Quantity[time, "Seconds"], 
 Quantity[distance, "Meters"]], which give {} as result... Lol wtf

Comment: Because the units are getting cancelled as solve sees it. What (v m/s) == (dist m)/(t s), when solved for dist simply gives v t because the units have cancelled. Use just dist without units and solve it.

Comment: Units are not cancelled totally. Remains only meters.

Comment: Look at the equation  (v m/s) == (dist m)/(t s) and tell me which unit remains Both m and s get cancelled don't they ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `distance` inside `Quantity[#,"Meters"]&` you can think of it as a unitless number that you are multiplying by "Meters".

Alternatively

```
Clear[distance, time, Vavg];
Solve[Quantity[Vavg, "Meters"/"Seconds"] == distance/Quantity[time, "Seconds"], distance]

(* {{distance -> time Vavg (Quantity[1, "Meters"])}} *)
```

shows how you can an answer with units attached.

Comment: Looks nice , but before accepting the answer .... why it works if i dont put any units on distance. And another question , how do i apply to the solution the values 0.25 m/ s and  4.00 minutes ?